# Create columns with specific characters in string conditional on length of string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, if-statement, substring, case

I want to create new columns in a table that currently has two columns: "dx" and "dxlength". The new columns will be a substring of characters from column "dx" based on the length of characters in "dx" which can be found in column "dxlength".

For example, if the dxlength is >=3, then I would like to put the first three characters into a column named "first3".

I am trying to use a case when statement, but am getting several errors. What do I need to change to my code?

I have tried using a case when statement. See example code below.

```
select 
    dx, dxlength, 
    case when dxlength >= 3 then substring('dx', 1, 3) as first3, 
    case when dxlength >= 4 then substring('dx', 1, 4) as first4, 
    case when dxlength >= 5 then substring('dx', 1, 5) as first5, 
    case when dxlength >= 5 then substring('dx', 5, 1) as fifth, 
    case when dxlength >= 6 then substring('dx', 6, 1) as sixth, 
    case when dxlength < 7 then '!' as seventh, 
    case when dxlength = 7 then substring('dx', 7, 1) as seventh
into  
    table2
from
    table1
```

The table would have 7 additional columns that contain a substring of the characters in column "dx" based on the number of characters in "dx", which can be found in column "dx length".

Comment: Your `CASE` expressions don't end with `END` so that is an error there. Also your `dx` column references in the `substring()` formula is quoted so it's being treated as a string-literal. Like literally the word `dx`. Instead: `case when dxlength>=3 then substring(dx,1,3) END as first3, `

Comment: you script is missing end , please add a sample data and the wished output https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/case.php

Comment: Resolved! Thanks so much.